# bluetooth does not appear on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluetooth

I do not find the Bluetooth icon. Is there any way to setup the bluetooth in my laptop using Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: If your Laptop does not have Bluetooth built in/connected externally, then the icon won't appear on the top bar. Check the system settings to see if you can enable Bluetooth from there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output and find dmesg:

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

Also update the firmware:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Comment: Didn't worked.. :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should specify your question:

- which Bluetooth adapter do you use?
- is it onboard or usb?
- for what do you need the bluetoothconnection for?

Then check whether bluez:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluez-utils libopenobex1
```

if you use gnome as windowmanager additionally install

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-bluetooth
```

Do these commands return errors? Is the software already installed?